# How to specify insertId when streaming insert to BigQuery using Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

BigQuery supports de-duplication for streaming insert. How can I use this feature using Apache Beam?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency

> To help ensure data consistency, you can supply insertId for each inserted row. BigQuery remembers this ID for at least one minute. If you try to stream the same set of rows within that time period and the insertId property is set, BigQuery uses the insertId property to de-duplicate your data on a best effort basis. You might have to retry an insert because there's no way to determine the state of a streaming insert under certain error conditions, such as network errors between your system and BigQuery or internal errors within BigQuery. If you retry an insert, use the same insertId for the same set of rows so that BigQuery can attempt to de-duplicate your data. For more information, see troubleshooting streaming inserts.

I can not find such feature in Java doc.
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401195/apache-beam-bigquery-insertid-for-deduplication-not-working), he suggest to set insertId in TableRow. Is this correct?

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html?is-external=true

BigQuery client library has this feature.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/InsertAllRequest.java#L134

Comment: Can you specify more about your use case? Dataflow/Beam should perform only-once when coupled with BigQuery, without you needing to specify manually an insertId.

Comment: my use case is mentioned above. want to de-duplicate when inserting to BigQuery. so just specify insertId as column in new row?

Comment: I understand you want to de-duplicate. But depending on the source of duplication, this might be already a solved problem.

Comment: no duplication on data source side. since Kafka support at least once delivery as default so I think there is possibility of duplication between Kafka producer and consumer. and also I guess dataflow might insert same row more than once when retry on some errors (e.g. temporal network issue). so I just want to know how I can avoid duplication on both. this question is about stream insert from dataflow to bigquery.

Comment: In my actual use case, requirement for de-duplication is not so strong. So I think the easiest way is just to insert to Big Query then de-duplication on query. but I just want to know BigQueryIO (Apache Beam) support deduplication feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felipe mentioned in the comment, it seems that Dataflow is already using insertId for itself to implement "exactly once". so we can not manually specify insertId.

Answer (score 3):

- **Pub/Sub + Beam/Dataflow + BigQuery**: "Exactly once" should be guaranteed, and you don't need to worry much about this. That guarantee is stronger when you ask Dataflow to insert to BigQuery using [FILE_LOADS](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#FILE_LOADS) instead of [STREAMING_INSERTS](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#STREAMING_INSERTS), for now.
- **Kafka + Beam/Dataflow + BigQuery**: If a message can be emitted more than once from Kafka (e.g. if the producer retried the insertion), then you need to take care of de-duplication. Either in BigQuery (as currently implemented, according to your comment), or in Dataflow with a `.apply(Distinct.create())` transform.

Comment: Thanks! but my original question is how to use BigQuery deduplication feature from Apache Beam.

Comment: You can't manually, because Dataflow is already using insertId for itself to implement "exactly once" as described.

Comment: OK I see. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for asking! I had to ask some experts to get to this answer :). Including Pablo, who improved my answer above

Comment: And I can not find about `.apply(Distinct.create())` transform in Apache Beam document. So it would be helpful if you could mention about it in the document.

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.html

Comment: I mean it is not easy to find it in japadoc without any explanation in Apache beam website

Comment: I'm confused now

Comment: "Dataflow is already using insertId for itself to implement "exactly once" as described"  Can I see how this is implemented? Would you provide the link to this implementation? Thanks.

Comment: Re: "That guarantee is stronger when you ask Dataflow to insert to BigQuery using FILE_LOADS instead of STREAMING_INSERTS, for now". Is it really a "guarantee" that duplicate can't possibly happen? if so, why one is stronger than the other?